# Get only sub-directories with Git?

Tags: git

I am trying to set up a version control system of our existing code and I chose Git but I am quite new with this.

We have a server with a Git repository: *MyProject*.
Now in this repository there are several directories each corresponding to a tool (which may be used independently of the others):
*MyProject/Tool1, MyProject/Tool2, MyProject/Tool3*, etc...

Is it possible for a contributor to not *pull* the whole project on his local machine but just on directory (for exemple *Tool1*), work on it and modify it and then *push* it on the server?

How can this be achieved?

Thank you.

Comment: You should work with branches, create a branch for every tool and work on these. Then when you have a stable version of one of these, merge to the main branch (probably named development). When everything is stable on dev, merge to master, the main branch. That way everybody who works on Tool1 will have the same code for the other tools (which will be the code from the last merge to dev). -- Google branches and if you're interested I'd be happy to clarify in an answer.

Comment: If the tools are actually independent of each other, they should be separate repositories. (Git isn't like a VCS like Subversion or Perforce where everything goes into one repo.)

Comment: @ShellFish, Git's branches are not a good solution for working on separate tools. Branches in Git are for working on different versions of the same code, not entirely separate codebases. mipadi's comment is a better suggestion.

Comment: True story, although it's the best solution available if the OP wishes to keep everything in one repo.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am not really happy with the "branches solutions". Firstly because it is not really the purpose of branches to be used that way, and more important, I am certainly the most "geeky" of all the contributors (and this why I am in charge of setting up the VCS), and I am affraid that dealing with different branches, specially with a non common use, will be to complecated for the other contributors.

Comment: I will may be use Mipadi's solution with separate repositories. Can I after make a big main depository including all the sub-repositories at their last version? This will be easier to handle to distribute the whole software suite after.

Comment: You could look into using Git submodules, which will allow each subdirectory to behave (to some degree) like a separate repository.  Then each contributor could just clone the Tool directory of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep your *Tool1*, *Tool2*, etc., projects in separate git repositories to allow them to be pulled, modified, and pushed independently.

Your top level *MyProject* repository can then be yet another separate git repository and you can use `git submodule add` to add the *Tool* subdirectories as git submodules.  This way you can pull the entire *MyProject* repository including the independent submodules.